# Guaranteed order in SQL batch update?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

Assume the item list contains item1, item2 and item3. Does the DB insert my items in this order as well?

```
List<Item> items = ...
List<Map<String, Object>> batchValues = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
for (Item item : items) {
    Map<String, Object> namedParameters = ...
    batchValues.add(namedParameters);
}
getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(SQL_INSERT_ITEMS, batchValues.toArray(new Map[0]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational databases don't maintain an insertion order. When you query the records back out you can specify the order you want them in with an `order by` clause. If you need the records to be ordered the way you inserted them, you will have to manually store a number into a field on the record. Some databases will have an auto-increment option for a table column, or a sequence generator (Oracle) that you can use.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it does, otherwise it would be pretty worthless.

And by the way, you should change this code:

```
batchValues.toArray(new Map[0])
```

to

```
batchValues.toArray(new Map[batchValues.size()])
```

Comment: My question might be more related to the actual insert into the DB then with Spring. Will my items be inserted in the same order as my item list? ...and no I don't know much about DBs.